# Apache Camel jms component based application consuming memory in idle time

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have apache camel jms component based application, with spring integration and deployed in tomcat. JMS connection details are coming from JNDI(configured in tomcat). Message broker is IBM MQ 8. when i am connecting via JConsole it's showing memory spike graph even though there is no active flow in Camel.
Please find the JConsole screen for the same. Could you please help me to identify why application is continuously using memory in idle time. Let me know if you need more details.

> application flow: consume message -> do some db operation (mostly select queries) -> form response -> send response to JMSReply queue

[image]

.

Comment: What version of Camel are you using?

Comment: spring.version: 4.0.5.RELEASE, 
camel.version: 2.13.0